# Setting user and password for JMS queue

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ and Java JMS.

**Is it possible to set user and password for a JMS queue?**

The user and password should be provided when making connection to the queue.

I dont want to allow any user to get messages from my queue...

Comment: Normally a user is given a password and that user is permissioned to use a resource such a queue.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Where does this user get this permission? how does the queue know which user is allowed to connect?

Comment: You have to configure the broker which manages the queue.  I haven't done this for about 7 years so I don't remember the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read [ActiveMQ Security Docs](http://activemq.apache.org/security.html) since it's explaining this in detail.

Basically, you setup users/passwords and assign them to roles on the Broker you connect to. You specify the user/password when you create the connection in JMS.

Then you can specify wich queues are accesible by wath roles. You can even setup a prefix, such as "FINANCE." or "HR.", so that all queues such as HR.NEW.EMPLOYEES could be assigned to the HR role etc.

Really, read the documentation linked to.